# get a record from obj A which is created after 3 minutes of another record in another object obj B

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I am unable to form a SOQL query to get a record for below scenario.
Get a record from obj A which is created after 3 minutes of another record in another object obj B.

And also i want to get first record that is created after 3 minutes, can we get a first record that is created within timeframe of 3 minutes not all of them. Keeping a limit, not giving exact record.

Please help.

Comment: sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why 3 minutes ? do you mean  180 seconds? what if it will be 181 or 179 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`addMinutes`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) either to stored DateTime variable or directly in your SOQL

```
ObjB__c bRec= [select createdDate from ObjB__c where id = 'your id'];
System.debug([select id from ObjA__c where createdDate > :bRec.createdDate.addMinutes(3)]);
```

Comment: thanks, and also if i do this i will get all the records that are created after 3 minutes, can we get a first record that is created within timeframe of 3 minutes

Comment: You could add `limit 1` along with `order by createdDate desc` where desc would be optional

Answer (score 0):

[Pranav Parakh](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/60662/pranav-parakh) is right. You can get the first record of `objA` created `after 3 minutes` of a record of `objB` created using `LIMIT 1` and `ORDER BY`.

I have here just added `List` to `SOQL` query result to avoid `null exception`. I have also used [addSeconds()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) method instead of `addMinutes()`

```
    List<objB__c> objB = [SELECT CreatedDate FROM objB__c WHERE Id='objBRecodId'];

    if(objB.size() > 0){
        List<objA__c> objA = [SELECT Id, Name 
                              FROM objA__c 
                              WHERE CreatedDate > :objB[0].CreatedDate.addSeconds(180) 
                              ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
                              LIMIT 1];

        if(objA.size() > 0){
           system.debug(objA[0]); 
        }
     }
```